# my system refuses to shut down/restart with NSAppleScript class

Tags: objective-c, applescript, macos-carbon, core-foundation, finder

I am using `CFPlugin` for contextual menu and icon overlay on 10.5(same as `scplugin`). For communication between my application and finder , i am using `distributed object`. After installing my plugin inside `Contextual menu items` folder , my system refuse to restart/shutdow/Logout. In activity monitor i am unable to quit finder , only force quit is woking for finder.
On console I am getting on 10.5.8

```
ERROR | -[ApplicationManager(AppleEventHandling) _tryQuitAllForRequestor:replyEvent:] | _tryQuitAllForRequestor - _vproc_set_global_on_demand returned error -1805620379
```

Without communication between Finder and my application, system restart/shutdow/Logout are working fine.
On 10.5.4

```
loginwindow[41]: ERROR | WSActivateApp | SetFrontProcess({0, 7980956}) returned error -600. Unable to activate process.

loginwindow[41]: ERROR | -[ApplicationManager(AppleEventHandling) _tryQuitAllForRequestor:replyEvent:] | _tryQuitAllForRequestor - _vproc_set_global_on_demand returned error -1780878507
```

Can anyone please help me out?

**EDIT**

My problem is solved. I was using `NSAppleScript` for executing apple script. Now i am using NSTask and my system restart/shutdow/Logout are working fine. can anyone please explain me reason for this?

Comment: I notice that when you're called from an app other than the Finder, you return "noErr". What do you return when you are called from the Finder?

Comment: If application is finder , i am executing my code.

Comment: And then what does it return?

Comment: it will return OSStatus, error or noErr.

Comment: without communication module, my plug-in is working fine.

Comment: are you initiating a DO transaction in the shutdown process? It looks like Finder is waiting a reply from your IPC server.

Comment: My problem is solved. I was using NSAppleScript for executing apple script. Now i am using NSTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. I was using `NSAppleScript` for executing apple script. Now i am using `NSTask` and my system restart/shutdow/Logout are working fine

Answer (score 1):

NSAppleScript can only be run from the main thread, so the main thread is going to be blocked while it is running.

Not too sure what is the root cause of the message, but I am supposing the script can not be found or run properly, and then the main thread is blocked or timed out, and all your shutdown sequence gets stuck.

On the opposite side, NSTask is properly multithreaded so the sequence won't be blocked, and your computer will properly shutdown.

Here are a few relevant links gathered around:

- http://deusty.blogspot.com/2006/11/nsapplescript-is-slow.html
- [NSTask Launch causing crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607606/nstask-launch-causing-crash)
- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/226818-nsapplescript-returns-wrong-result-on-multiple-safari-windows-applescript-editor-work.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I was running Apple script from secondary thread. and only one thread at a time.

Comment: From (NSAppleScript not in the main thread)[http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/163902-nsapplescript-not-in-the-main-thread.html#164093]
'All NSAppleScript instance seem to use the same ComponentInstance also the ComponentInstance may also be used by the main thread, to set up the application to be AppleScriptable perhaps. Each thread must have its own AppleScript ComponentInstance, in theory this you could have multiple thread each running there own AppleScript'

I am assuming that finder is not using NSApplescript class.